# AFNetworking Expected status code in (200-299), got 403

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, afnetworking

Trying to migrate my code from `ASIHttpRequest` to `AFNetworking`. It seems similar questions has been asked but `couldnt` find solution to my problem.

My code was working fine with `ASIHttpRquest`.

I send a simple post request to my server and listen http responses. If `http response` is 200 everything works fine but if I send another status code >400 `AFNetworking` block fails.

Server side response:

```
$rc = $stmt->fetch();
    if ( !$rc ) {
    //  echo "no such record\n";
      $isrecordExist=0; //false does not exists
      sendResponse(403, 'Login Failed');
      return false;
    }
    else {
     // echo 'result: ', $result, "\n";
       $sendarray = array(
            "user_id" => $result,
        );
        sendResponse(200, json_encode($sendarray));
    }
```

IOS Part:

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:
                            [NSURL URLWithString:server]];
    client.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate=YES;

    [client postPath:loginForSavingCredientials parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
    if (operation.response.statusCode == 500) {}
     else if (operation.response.statusCode == 403) {}
     else if (operation.response.statusCode == 200) {//able to get results here            NSError* error;
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary* json =     [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                                 options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                   error: &error];}
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"failure %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
```

NSLOG:

```
 failure Expected status code in (200-299), got 403
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When `AFNetworking` gets a 2xx (success) status code, it calls the success block.

When it gets a 4xx (client error) or 5xx (server error) status code, it calls the failure block because something went wrong.

So all you should need to do is move your check for a 500 or 403 status code to the failure block.

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:server]];
client.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate=YES;

[client postPath:loginForSavingCredientials parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id response) {
    if (operation.response.statusCode == 200) {//able to get results here            NSError* error;
        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                             options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                               error: &error];
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failure %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    if (operation.response.statusCode == 500) {}
    else if (operation.response.statusCode == 403) {}
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the request operation you need to tell it which response status codes are acceptable (mean success). By default this is codes in the range 200 -> 299.

Setup before you start using the client:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation.acceptableStatusCodes = ...;

[client postPath:
```

Docs are [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperation.h).